# A [criterion] for renaming?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The [criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criterion) tag is supposed to be used for questions about [haskell/criterion](https://github.com/haskell/criterion), a benchmarking library, but half of the new questions aren't about Haskell at all. Can it be renamed to [haskell-criterion]? (While I know nothing about Haskell this seems like the best option. The old tag can be made a synonym but I'm not sure that it matters.)

Note: some of the mistagged questions seem to have better suited tags such as [jpa-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jpa-criteria) and [hibernate-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hibernate-criteria). I'm not sure what to think of [criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/criteria), which seems like a big mess that I definitely don't have the expertise to sort out.

For [Snaipe/Criterion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion) I created [c-criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-criterion) (may not be the best name).

Comment: Seems like there's a C/C++ [Criterion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion) [Library](https://criterion.readthedocs.io/en/master/intro.html) at a minimum.  There's a concept of [Information Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection#Criteria) in statistics associated with modeling (AIC/BIC/DIC/FIC/KIC) which would be off-topic unless it were implemented in code (which it probably is in R and elsewhere).

Comment: Seems reasonable. Re-tag the questions not related to the library, and ping me afterwards. I'll rename it. As for [criteria], we'll probably have to burn the tag, but that's a separate discussion. Awfully named libraries though.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It should be good to go. (I made sure that there are no [criterion] questions without the [haskell] tag.)